# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ... \jzmq.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, jzmq

I have a java application using ZMQ. I've been able to run it on my Win7 PC where I placed the jzmq.dll in the same folder where the jar executable is, then I run it by the command "java -jar myapp.jar".

My next step is to move it to run on a server. So I copied it all over to the server (Win 2008), the files as well as the directory structure. Apparently the very same command that gets it to work on my PC doesn't work on the server.
Any ideas why and what should I do to get it run on the server as well?

Following the first comment below I've copied to the server all the ZMQ related folders I have, preserving their directory structure. Still getting the same error. More details on the error message are:

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what "can't find dependent libraries" means? It means that the DLL depends on one or more *other* DLLs, that aren't installed.

Comment: Thanks EJP. I've added data to my question following your response.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. `jzmq.dll` relies on other DLLs that you haven't installed. "Copy" isn't necessarily a valid installation procedure.

Comment: Are you familiar with zmq?

Comment: The only thing I need to know about it is that you haven't installed it correctly, and I only know that because the error message says so.

Answer (score 0):

jzmq.dll needs the related libzmq.dll whose libzmq.lib is used to compile. Now you may think adding libzmq.dll to system load path and hope to get zmq running. It won't. **You need to change the name of libzmq.dll to the versioned one.** In my case it's "libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll".